# Correct Palm Icon Height

Tags: icons, palm-os

As I like to develop some applications for Palm OS, normally I have problems with the icon height for the applications. When I create 32x32 icon, the icon gets even behind the name of the program, because of it size. But what is the correct height of icons for Palm OS? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The large application icons are 32x22 (low-density) and 64x44 (high-density). The small application icons are 15x9 (low-density) and 30x18 (high-density).

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about icons and icon sets used in your application, the original low-density format had a size of 10 x 9 (width x height).  The high-density format has a size of 20 x 18.

Comment: Did you forget about large icons?  Even for the small icons, I don't think 10x9/20x18 were ever standard sizes.  I think for as long as small icons have been around, they've always been at least 15x9.

Comment: The icon sizes I'm referring to are the de-facto standards for icons within applications.  Like the status icons used in calender and task lists applications.  I was not making a reference to 'desktop' icons.